# Dual space of $\mathcal{C}_0[a,b]$

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to calculate the dual space of $\mathcal{C}_0[a,b]$, that is the space of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ vanishing at $a$. I know that the dual of $\mathcal{C}[a,b]$ is the space of differences of Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures associated to increasing and left-continuous functions, vanishing at a point of $[a,b]$. Anyone can help me?

Comment: What are you looking for is called the Riesz-Markov theorem.

Comment: If $V \subset W$ then $V^\ast = W^\ast/ \text{something}$... The dual of a subspace is a quotient of the dual.

Comment: Cross-posted, with answer selected, at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/125139/dual-space-of-mathcalc-0a-b

Answer (score 2):

Consider functional
$$
\mathrm{ev}_a:\mathcal{C}([a,b])\to \mathbb{C}:f\mapsto f(a)
$$
 Note that for any closed subspace $E$ of Banach space $X$ holds
$$
E^*=X^*/E^\perp
$$
where
$$
E^\perp:=\{f\in X^*:f(E)=\{0\}\}
$$
Apply this to $E=\mathrm{Ker}(\mathrm{ev}_a)=\mathcal{C}_0([a,b])$, and $X=\mathcal{C}([a,b])$ to get
$$
\mathcal{C}_0([a,b])^*=\mathcal{C}([a,b])^* / \mathrm{Ker}(\mathrm{ev}_a)^\perp
=\mathcal{M}([a,b]) / \mathrm{span}\{\delta_a\}
$$
where $\delta_a$ is a Dirac delta measure centered at point $a$.